# Symfony2: Doctrine does not load related entities in many-to-many relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many-relation, and when I load an entity that is on one side this relation, I expect to see as its property the ArrayCollection of related entities on another side. However, this does not happen - the ArrayCollection loaded has no elements in it, while in the database I can see the related entries. What could be the reason?

Here is my code:
One side of the relation, ConsolidatedReport class:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="P24\Response",  inversedBy="consolidatedReports")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="con_rprt_responses")
 */
private $responses;
```

Another side of the relation, Response class:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="P24\ConsolidatedReport\ConsolidatedReport", mappedBy="responses")
 */
private $consolidatedReports;
```

Here is the function I run to get an instance of ConsolidatedReport. This function sits inside a service that is being called from container:

```
/**
 * Picks the consolidated report with given id.
 *
 * @param string $id
 *
 * @return ConsolidatedReport
 *
 * @throws NonExistentConsolidatedReportException if the survey doesn't exist
 */
public function pick($id)
{
    $report = $this->repository->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));

    if (!$report) {
        throw new NonExistentConsolidatedReportException($id);
    }

    return $report;
}'
```

In the database, there is "con_rprt_responses" table with two columns "consolidated_reports_id" and "response_id". However, in profiler I do not see any queries to that table.

What could go wrong here?

***UPDATE:
Please see my answer to this question below, that worked for me.***

Comment: In profiler, I don't see any queries made to "con_rpt_responses" table.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I added `fetch="EAGER"` to the $responses property of ConsolidatedReport class, and it worked.

The code now looks like this:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="P24\Response", inversedBy="consolidatedReports", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="con_rprt_responses")
 */
private $responses;
```

More info here:
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-eager-loading

*Still if someone knows why the collection of related entity would not load without explicitly specifying EAGER fetching - please share your knowledge, it is highly appreciated!*

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a one-to-many relation, and `fetch="EAGER"` resolved it too. It's very odd. Did you ever figure out why eager fetching was required?

Comment: in my case the annotation comment had wrong format, the mapping was not parsed and yet not loaded

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the joinColumns, does this solve your problem?

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="P24\Response",  inversedBy="consolidatedReports")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="con_rprt_responses",
 * joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="consolidated_reports_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="response_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

The *toMany properties have to be initialized with an ArrayCollection.

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->responses = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this-> consolidatedReports = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have **more then single query** to fetch the same objects using Doctrine try to use:

```
$entityManager->clear();
```

in between, to fix "missing" entities. It isn't solution "as is", however can give you an idea something wrong in chain of your queries.